# Mach-Zehnder Interferometer question

Tags: quantum-mechanics, optics

I'm self-studying QM by using a resource on MIT-OCW and I am not quite confident if I am understanding this problem correctly.
[image]

First of all I'm not sure if I should assume both beam splitter should be the same.

Assuming I do, my approach is the following:

Let the top input beam $a$ and bottom input beam $b$. Then by the beam $a$ will be split into one up and one down beam by some coefficient $k$ so that vector up |a+> $=k(a,0)$ and down|a-> = $(1-k)(0,a)$. I would do the same for $b$ to get |b+> $= (1-k)(b,0)$ and     |b-> $= k(0,b)$ by symmetry.
This will give the emerged upper beam vector to be $(ka+(1-k)b, 0)$ and lower beam $e^{i\gamma}(0, kb+(1-k)a)$ (I am not sure what the meaning of this phase shifting is...). Then I would do similar process for emerging beam going through the second beam splitter.

I am not sure if I am understanding the question correct and if I am allowed to write the beam splitting ratio as just $k$ and $k-1$.

Any comment and help on how to approach this problem will be very helpful!